# How to sort f:selectItems in each p:selectOneMenu of my application?

Tags: sorting, jsf, selectonemenu

Eg:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{UserBean.country}" id="countryId">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Japan" itemValue="Japan"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Russia" itemValue="Russia"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="India" itemValue="India"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{UserBean.onChangeCountry}" process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Like above I have many other selectOneMenu in other jsf pages which is not in sorted form, I want a solution where in surrounding the selectOneMenu tag with the custom tag will display the contents in sorting  order (or can suggest any other way also we can achieve this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom renderer for the `p:selectOneMenu` component. Create a new class, say `my.custom.MySelectOneMenuRenderer`, and extend `SelectOneMenuRenderer`. In this you want to `@Override` the `encodeInput` method to something like:

```java
public class MySelectOneMenuRenderer extends SelectOneMenuRenderer {

  @Override
  protected void encodeInput(FacesContext context, SelectOneMenu menu, String clientId, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Object values, Object submittedValues, Converter converter) throws IOException {
    // Sort the items
    Collections.sort(selectItems, Comparator.comparing(SelectItem::getLabel));
    // Delegate to super to continue rendering
    super.encodeInput(context, menu, clientId, selectItems, values, submittedValues, converter);
  }

}
```

I've checked this with PrimeFaces 10. If you need the source for a different PrimeFaces version, check the [`SelectOneMenuRenderer` source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/10.0.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenuRenderer.java) and select the according version tag (note that from PrimeFaces 11 the [path changed](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenuRenderer.java)). Note that the method you need to override, might be different in other versions (not likely, but possible).

Add your custom renderer to the `render-kit` section in your `faces-config.xml` like:

```xml
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>my.custom.MySelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Please note that this will sort the options every time for any `p:selectOneMenu` render, which comes with a performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a custom tag.

In the case of a `p:selectOneMenu` you can just use `f:selectItems` (plural) and return a sorted collection (replacing your individual `f:selectItem` tags). In this case, that would be something like;

```
<f:selectItems value="#{view.countries}"/>
```

Where `countries` is a getter, `getCountries()`, returning a list of `Map<String, String>` sorted according to your choice.

Imagine for a second there was no `f:selectItems` though, and the only option available to us was `f:selectItem` (singular) - like in your example. Then the solution would be to use a JSF pre-render hook and sort the JSF components before that section was rendered. You can read exactly how this works here; [Variable order of components (panels) in JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189816/variable-order-of-components-panels-in-jsf-page/54193497#54193497). In that example, a list of `p:panel` components are shuffled randomly inside a `h:panelGroup`. It can easily be applied to this case though.

To make it more transparent and hide the `f:event` tag to the pre-render hook on the pages, you could go one step further and define a composite component;

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info

This composite component could just use a `selectOneMenu` and introduce a `sort` attribute that would allow you to invoke the sorting pre-render hook as described above depending on if the value of the `sort` attribute is true or false.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution and this solution is like we need to keep sorting from bean for many such lists we use in different xhtml pages across our application, also the above which I showed is just an example but actually I have used f:selectItems with list as its value. But we need a custom tag which extends selectOneMenu and do sorting of the uicomponent list value, instead of using selectOneMenu we will use this custom component in xhtml page which will take care of sorting these list values.

Comment: @roopashreer Extended my answer slightly.